# Looping within a loop of a recordset

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Just for reference I am using Laravel 5.

I have a two tables

```
users 
    id
    first name

skills
    id
    name
```

and a pivot table

```
skill_user
    skill_id
    user_id
```

if I do a select in MySQL as follows:

```
select users.id as id, users.first_name, skills.name from users 
left join skill_user on users.id = skill_user.user_id
left join skills on skill_user.skill_id=skills.id
```

I get:

```
id, first_name, skill
1, Jenna, Reliable
1, Jenna, Organized
2, Alex, Hardworking
3, Barry, Capable
3, Barry, Amiable
3, Barry, Patient
4, Janine, (null)
```

I pass this through to a view via a Controller:

```
$peoples = [];
$peoples = \DB::table('users')
->select(\DB::raw('users.id as id, first_name, skill.name as name"'))
->leftJoin('skill_user','users.id','=','skill_user.user_id')
->leftJoin('skills','skill_user.skill_id','=','skills.id')
->get();
return view('find-people', compact(['peoples']));
```

Now, I want to loop through this in the view (pseudocode):

```
forelse ( peoples as people )
    people - > first_name
    people - > skill
empty
    no people found
endforelse
```

Which all works fine in a sense - but the first name gets repeated when there is more than one skill.

I can probably hack a loop of the skills by doing something like comparing user_id to itself but it seems such a clumsy way to do it.

```
user_id = $peoples->id
while (some looping criteria)
{
    write out skills
    if($peoples->id != user_id){break;}
}
```

How do I loop through the recordset in an elegant/eloquent fashion? Or is there a better entirely to do this?

Comment: Just found this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-for-loop-wmultiple-relations/?page=1 - which is probably the kind of direction I should be looking at.

Comment: I think what you actually want to create is a `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` relationship in your models. This way, you can do `$people->skills` and get back all of the skills for that individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the relationships in your models you don't need to try and construct raw SQL to achieve that. This is what the Laravel ORM "Eloquent" is for!

```
class People extends Model {
    public function skills () {
        return $this->hasMany('Skill');
    }
}
```

Then you define the skill model :

```
class Skill extends Model {
    public function People () {
        return $this->belongsToMany('People');
    }
}
```

Now you're able to iterate over the `People` model and for each person, get their `->skills`. This way you don't end up with the duplicate issue you're experiencing and you greatly simplify the SQL you're trying to achieve by leveraging the ORM.

Comment: Perfect: what I did was to create: 

$peopleinfos = User::with('skills')->get();

And it works perfectly!

Comment: just so this hopefully helps someone else; my display loop looks like  this: @foreach ($peopleinfo->skills as $name) <p> {{ $name->name }}</p> @endforeach; That way it only displays the skill name and not the whole array.